# htaccess redirect url by adding parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Need Guidance of 301 redirecting Url through htaccess matching specific format

```
Existing URL

http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_toys&limitstart=20

Proposed URL

http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_toys&view=list&Itemid=2&limitstart=20
```

Here limitstart may change to 0,20,40,60 to even 1000 and thus should remain same in the new proposed url too

Can anyone advise on to redirect using htaccess of above

Comment: This sounds more like a PHP issue than an `.htaccess` issue. Aren't you passing through `Itemid` and `view` as `_GET` parameters?

Comment: Well i am but unfortunately Google crawl has crawled some pages like the existing url, so as to have sync - is considering a htaccess solution so as to redirect all in same format as in proposed url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match query string using `RewriteCond` using a regex to capture both parameters:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(option=com_toys)&(limitstart=\d+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1&view=list&Itemid=2&%2 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi thanks - but its displaying in incorrect url :- `http://www.example.com/index.php?view=list&Itemid=2&option=com_toys&limitstart=120` instead of `http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_toys&view=list&Itemid=2&limitstart=120`

Comment: It is actually same URL just that parameters are in different order.

Comment: This will impact in Search as Google crawl will treat it as duplicate url, is it possible to get parameters in same order